# Unorthodox question, but I need help knowing where these images came from

Tags: images, icon, resource-recommendations, stock-images

So I had some work done for me and I got a bunch of small simple images in the doc but I don't know where I can find similarly styled images for the future.

Here's a few of them: 
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Does anyone recognize where these would be from?
I think they may be connected to Microsoft PP but I'm not sure.

Thanks for the help! If there's a more appropriate place to ask this question let me know.

Comment: Have you considered reaching out to the person that did the work?

Comment: I could but I think that'd make it obvious that I think I can do the job on my own in the future... Plus we don't speak the same native language which makes it more difficult.

Comment: I don't see how you've arrived at either of those conclusions. "Hi, I really like the icons you've used. Are these free or downloadable on the Internet? I'd like to use them in an instruction guide I am creating and would love to use more icons. Take care!" In regards to the language barrier, how the heck did the work get performed in the first place. If a consultant is worried that revealing an icon set is going to jeopardize their livelihood then that is quite a big red flag for me that I'd rather find out sooner than later.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus you're right, I'm wrong. Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

There are thousands of similar — and possibly identical — icons on the [Noun Project](https://thenounproject.com) website.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so miuch!

Answer (score 4):

I don't think these icons come from the same set.

- [SDK](https://www.iconfinder.com/icons/4865086/document_extension_file_file_type_format_sdk_type_icon)
- [WWW](https://icons8.com/icon/1349/website)
- [Gamepad](https://www.onlinewebfonts.com/icon/557349)

I couldn't find the first one or the phone.

Comment: Phone is not same

Answer (score 3):

In Windows search for Character Map 
and There select the Webdings or Wingdings Font to get these type of Icons
Just Copy them and Paste in any Software by taking Text Tool
Thanks